# Find an explicit scheme with local truncation error $O(\tau+h^2)$ for the method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We have the following problem:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-8t-6x, 0<x<1,0<t\le1 \\ 
u(x,0)=x^3, 0\le x\le 1 \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=0, u(1,t)=1-4t^2, 0<t\le 1
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Find an explicit difference scheme with step $\tau$ for the time t, and step h for the distance x with local truncation error $O(\tau+h^2)$

My solution is:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
y_i^{j+1}=y_i^j+\frac{\tau}{h^2}(y_{i+1}^j-2y_i^j+y_{i-1}^j)
-8\tau^2 j-6h\tau i\\
y_i^0=(hi)^3 \\
y_n^j=1-(2\tau j)^2 \\
y_1^j=y_0^j
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

We see that that the last difference equation has local truncation error $O(h)$, so I did the following substitution using the first differential equation:

$$
\frac{u_1^j-u_0^j}{h}=0+z+O(h^2) \implies \frac{u_1^j-u_0^j}{h}+z=0
$$

We see that z is the local truncation error,

$$
\psi_{h,\tau}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}|_0^j \frac{h}{2}+O(h^2)
$$

We express the first PDE in the form

$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+8t+6x, 0<x<1,0<t\le1
$$

and we substitute in the last differential equation with the assumption that it is defined in the $0^{th}$ point so that we express it with local truncation error $O(h^2)$

$$
\frac{y_1^j-y_0^j}{h}-\frac{h}{2}(\frac{y_0^{j+1}-y_0^j}{\tau}+8\tau j+6hi)
$$

which expressed canonically looks like this:

$$
y_0^{j+1}=\frac{2\tau}{h^2}(y_1^j-y_0^j)-8\tau^2j-6h\tau i$$

Is my solution correct? Thanks in advance!